# DataTable Jquery Length change bug problem

Tags: jquery, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to length change in dataTable

here is my code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>
                Internet
                Explorer 4.0
            </td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td> 4</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>
                Internet
                Explorer 5.0
            </td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>
                Internet
                Explorer 5.5
            </td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>
                Internet
                Explorer 6
            </td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.9</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>125.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>312.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>419.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>522.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>420</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td>420.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>413</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td>8.5</td>
            <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td>3.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    @*<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>*@
</table>
<!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- JQVMap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
<!-- overlayScrollbars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
<!-- Daterange picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!-- summernote -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">
@*
    <!-- JsGrid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/plugins/jsgrid/demos/demos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/plugins/jsgrid/css/jsgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/plugins/jsgrid/css/theme.css" />
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
*@
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE -->
<script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables  & Plugins -->
<script src="~/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/datatables-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#example1 thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#example1 thead');
            $('#example1 thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (i) {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');

                $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                        table
                            .column(i)
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });

            var table = $("#example1").DataTable({
                "orderCellsTop": true,
                "fixedHeader": true,
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
                }
                @*"buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]*@
            });@*.buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');*@
        });
</script>
```

but when I'm trying to change showing entity list, (such as 10, 25, 50, 100)
bug happens.

showing 10 entities is fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESAxX.jpg)

but when I change to showing 25 entities,
bugs happens
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIvOc.png)

red box is happened in footer. (created new filter in footer)

of course, top filter is exist too.

how can I remove footer filter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are using multiple plugins scripts reference, but I'm not sure which version of DataTable plugin you are using, can you explain more detail about it?

According to the [DataTable examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html), I create a sample using your code and use the following Javascript library files, the data table works well:

```
@section Scripts{

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#example1 thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#example1 thead');
            $('#example1 thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (i) {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');

                $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                        table
                            .column(i)
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });

            var table = $("#example1").DataTable({
                "orderCellsTop": true,
                "fixedHeader": true,
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
                }
                @*"buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]*@
            });@*.buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');*@
        });
    </script>
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

So, the issue might relate another CSS library or your custom CSS style, try to update or remove them. And you could also just use the above JavaScript scripts reference and CSS library files and remove other references.